# Java basic GUI program errors

Tags: java, user-interface

In my online Java class, I need to write a program that counts the number of mouse clicks on a button within a frame. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class option1 extends Frame {
    option1() {
        setTitle("Final Project Option 1");
        setSize(300,300);
        show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        option1 test = new option1();

        int a = 0;
        String s1 = "" + a;

        Frame objFrame;
        Button objButton1;
        Label objLabel1;

        objFrame = new option1();
        objButton1 = new Button("Button");
        objLabel1 = new Label();

        objLabel1.setBounds(150,220,50,30);
        objButton1.setBounds(40,35,50,50);

        objLabel1.setText(s1);

        objButton1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener()); //line 29

        objFrame.add(objLabel1);
        objFrame.add(objButton1);
    }
    public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            a++; //line 36
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get two errors. One error is on line 29, which is "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context", and the other is on line 36, which is "cannot find symbol".

So, what exactly am I doing wrong? I would appreciate responders telling exactly what I need to do to fix the problem, and avoiding using technical terms since I'm rather new to programming.

Comment: I think you better start looking Java language basics, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/
then Specially this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: and this 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to make your code working. But there is some issues regarding the standard Java coding. But you should consider previous answers concerning the coding style.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Frame mainFrame = new OptionOne();
    Button button = new Button("Button");
    final Label label = new Label();

    label.setBounds(150, 220, 50, 30);
    label.setText("0");
    button.setBounds(40, 35, 50, 50);

    label.addPropertyChangeListener(label.getText(), new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            mainFrame.addNotify();
        }
    });

    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());
            label.setText(String.valueOf(value + 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });

    mainFrame.add(label);
    mainFrame.add(button);
 }
}

class OptionOne extends Frame {

   OptionOne() {
    setTitle("Final Project Option 1");
    setSize(300, 300);
    show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling addNotify on EVERY PropertyChange event of the label? You should ever need to call addNotify...

Comment: Sure, is not necessary. Thank you @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues, namely your inner class should be `static` (to use it without an instance of `option1` which should probably be `Option1` to fit with Java naming conventions) and you need to define and initialize `a`. Something like

```
public static class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    int a = 0; //<-- add this.
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        a++; 
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest you consider using the more modern [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) instead of the older `Frame`.

**Edit**

You'll need to save a reference to your `MouseListener` like

```
MyMouseListener mml = new MyMouseListener();
objButton1.addMouseListener(mml);
```

Then you can get it the `a` like

```
System.out.println(mml.a);
```

Finally, your original approach of `"" + a` would be `"0"`.

Comment: I tried that, making the inner class static and moving "int a = 0" down to under the inner class. But now I have a different error when compiling: in the line "String s1 = "" + a;" I get an error "cannot find symbol".

Comment: @randomguy537 Edited. Obviously the `a` is part of the Listener; you should read up on variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, as soon as you possibly can, get out of the `main` method into a non-static context...

```
public class option1 extends Frame {
    private int a = 0;
    private Label objLabel1;
    option1() {
        setTitle("Final Project Option 1");
        setSize(300,300);


        Button objButton1;

        objButton1 = new Button("Button");
        objLabel1 = new Label();

        objLabel1.setBounds(150,220,50,30);
        objButton1.setBounds(40,35,50,50);

        objLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(a));

        objButton1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener()); //line 29

        add(objLabel1);
        add(objButton1);

        show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        option1 test = new option1();
    }
    public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            a++; //line 36
            objLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

- Generally speaking, AWT is out-of-date (by some 15 years) and you really should be trying to use Swing or JavaFX instead.
- Buttons should use `ActionListener`, as a mouse is not the only way a button might be triggered
- You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: `MyMouseListener` has no `a`.

Comment: When making the code like this (with the import lines in the beginning), I still have one (1) "cannot find symbol" error when compiling. It's in the line `objLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(a));` towards the end of the code.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It doesn't need it, the `MyMouseListener` is not a static inner class, it's an instance inner class, and can use the `a` from `option1`, as well as the label

Comment: @randomguy537 See how I made `objLable1` and instance field instead of delaring it within the constructor as a local variable...